# Update composer dependencies from command line

Tags: php, symfony, libraries, composer-php

I am currently working with symfony2 and I want to launch to download the libraries I need. I know the command in linux is *"$ ./composer.phar update --dev"* however when I run this in windows it prompts whether I should open the file with the windows explorer or not. I currently have composer.phar installed on windows but I am having trouble launching it. How would I be able to update my symfony2 folder with the dependencies I need. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have php in your `PATH`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that Windows don't know how to open .phar files. You need to execute them using php interpreter `php composer.phar update` and the php interpreter(php.exe) must be accessible on PATH.

You could use command `php -v` to check if your php is accessible from command line.

Answer (score 44):

In CMD:

```
php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update
```

Comment: Actually this answers different question.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar`
2. In CMD write  `php composer.phar` (**update**) or (**self-update**)

Answer (score 5):

1: Open cmd

2. First go to your work directory like if you have wamp then c:/wamp/www.
3. Then enter composer if you can see list of composer command then its good.
4. Now type "composer self-update".

5: Next you can see the process.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my Centos server

```
sudo -u nginx php composer.phar update
```